# How to Prevent RFID card reader imitation in html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, rfid

I'm using an RFID card reader to authenticate users into a web-service. The reader acts a keyboard, once it reads a card it "types" its serial number followed by a newline which submits the html form.

I'm trying to write a script that would detect if a user actually types a serial number into the input field rather than scanning a card.

My current solution is to make the input field look more like a button than like a field, but this is not an elegant solution.

Any better ideas?

Comment: the secret is the number, not the card. you can make the field invisible, but i don't see how it matters. to wit: if someone knows the number, they can burn an rfid and then your trust based on physical legitimacy will be unfounded.

Comment: do you recommend another technology then?

Comment: no, i think it's fine. credit cards are the same way. hide the input with opacity. the other idea i had (to actually help you) is to time the entry of the serial. a keyboard wedge will "machine gun" the keys in a very predictable manner, both in terms of total time and step time; even a slight variation on the timings would indicate foul play, and no human can match the exact timing in-between each key "press". ok, maybe one or two top drummers, but they likely don't want to scam your rfid.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and update you. Thanks

Comment: it works, I'll post the script as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following technique: detecting copy/paste and timing the intervals between the keystrokes. Here's my code.

html

```
<input name="card_number" id="card_number" oninput="detectHumans();" placeholder="SCAN CARD"/>
```

JS

```
        var x = -1;
        var delta = 0;
        var count = 0;
        function detectHumans() {
            count += 1;
            if ($("#card_number").val().length != count) {
                alert('human detected');
                $("body").html('');
            }
            console.log($("#card_number").val());
            y = Date.now();
            if (x == -1) {
                x = y;
            }
            else if (delta == 0) {
                delta = y - x;
                x = y;
            }
            else{
                var new_delta = y - x;
                console.log(delta);
                console.log(new_delta);
                if (Math.abs(new_delta - delta) > 10) {
                    alert('human detected');
                    $("body").html('');
                }
                delta = new_delta;
                x = y;
            }
        }
```